# App is not visible in Play Store of smart watch in section App in your phone

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

I have created the application both for Mobile and Watch. But my app is not present in Watch --> Play Store --> Apps on your Phone

I have created the signed apk of the watch and kept in the raw folder of the mobile application and then generate the signed apk of the mobile and after installing the app in mobile then I checked in watch it was not present.

**Wear**

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application 
    ....
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="false" />
</application>
```

In Gradle three productFlavors is been define

```
   prod {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        dimension "server"
    }
    dev {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        dimension "server"
    }
    testdev {
         versionCode 1
         versionName "0.0.1"
         dimension "server"
    }
```

**Mobile**

Gradle three productflavor

```
prod {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        dimension "server"
    }
    dev {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        dimension "server"
    }
    testdev {
         versionCode 1
         versionName "0.0.1"
         dimension "server"
    }

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'

//wearApp project(":wearable")
wearApp files("src/main/res/raw/wearable_app")
```

Manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
        android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wearableApp package="com.example.sample">
     <versionCode>1</versionCode>
     <versionName>0.0.1</versionName>
     <rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId>
</wearableApp>
```

wearable_app.apk is been kept in raw folder.

Both app is having same package name: `com.example.sample`.

Suppose I have generated the apk test release for both but in watch app is not visible.

What mistake am I making? I'm creating a signed release apk not debug apk.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no more Mobile/Wear bundle supported on WearOS 2+
You should create standalone watch app, which is installed just via Play Store

Comment: that means we have to upload two different bundle in play store

Comment: yes, I guess so.